# Core Data NSPredicate: Return all objects which are related to another object whos ID appears in a given array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

My object graph looks like this

Servers <-->> Events

Each event entity has an non-optional attribute ID.

An event can only belong to one server, but a server can be related to many events

Given an array of event IDs [1, 2, 3]

I want all the Servers that have an Event who's ID appears in the given array

I tried this but I get 'unable to parse the format string'

`NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(events, $event, ANY $event.clientID in %@)", clientIDs as CVarArg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `@count` to your subquery.

`NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(events, $event, ANY $event.clientID in %@).@count != 0", clientIDs as CVarArg)`

Checkout [these](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression/1411651-init/) docs for bit of a reference. It is for NSExpression but the "Discussion" section has an example of a subquery.

Comment: Thanks! This is correct

SUBQUERY(...) returns an array. We need to check if its count != 0 to return the true or false the predicate expects.